# Extrair imagens de um arquivo pdf atraves de um script python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

bom dia, 
Eu tenho este código

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
try:
    from textract import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    os.system('sudo apt-get install -y python3 python-dev python-pip build-essential swig git libpulse-dev && pip3 install pocketsphinx && pip3 install textract')
    os.system('pip3 install textract')
    from textract import *
# É inserido o ficheiro
ficheiro=input('insira o ficheiro pdf:')
#processa o ficheiro
data =process(ficheiro)
#imprime para o ecra e descodifica o texto
print (data.decode('utf8'))
```

O objetivo deste código era abrir um ficheiro pdf e a partir dele extrair texto e imagens porem ele apenas está pegando o texto

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score -1):

Em Python não sei, mas segue no Ubuntu:

1) Criar uma makefile. Segue como exemplo um ficheiro PDF chamado 'litle_invest' e diretório 'LI':

p1:

```
 mkdir -p LI
 pdfimages -all litle_invest.pdf nome da pasta/img
```

p2 litle_invest.txt: litle_invest.pdf

```
pdftotext litle_invest.pdf 
pdftotext -layout litle_invest.pdf 
pdftohtml  litle_invest.pdf
pdftohtml -xml  litle_invest.pdf
```

2) Na linha de comando:

$ make p1

$ make p2 (nesse caso, 'litle_invest.txt: litle_invest.pdf' é tudo na mesma linha mesmo, diferente do p1)

3) O resultado são todas as imagens extraídas do PDF para o diretório 'LI', e criada versões em txt, html e xml.

4) Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: adicione a sua resposta como um comentário ao invés de uma resposta, caso ela não esteja solucionando o problema.